# how to force which base file is used in template

Tags: django, django-admin, mezzanine

I would like to add custom view/template into the admin which I succeeded . But my issue here is that when I extends the base.html it takes the one from my project template and I would like to be able to tell django to take the one from mezzanine admin  (as it is a admin page and i would like to have the same look and feel as the rest of the admin)

Any idea how to force the template resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no special template names in django; "base.html" is just the conventional name for the template at the top of the template inheritance tree (which is not required to have a single parent or any particular structure at all).

In terms of templating, django admin is just another django app. The first step is to figure out which template contains the style and content you want to inherit. For this task, I use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar), which has a "Templates" panel which makes it very easy to figure out what content is coming from which template.

Looking at a django-debug-toolbar in the admin of a mezzanine site, you probably want to inherit from either "admin/base.html" or "admin/base_site.html" depending on how integrated your view is going to be with the admin site.